# php connect to mysqlworkbench localhost

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I have a mac with OSX 10.8.4. I have installed my localhost and it works just fine. I have made a php script, from where I would like to connect MySQL workbench database to. My apache tomcat server runs, and also mysql on the computer, and I use XAMPP. This is my code:

```
    <?php 

 // Establish connection to DB using PDO
 try {
  $pdo = new PDO('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '');
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
  echo "Connected!";
 } catch (PDOException $e) {  
  $error = 'ERROR - Connection to DB failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  echo "Connection failed";

  exit();
 }
```

I have tried this script to connect to a remote mysql server, where it works fine, but I cannot use it for my localhost. I also tried just to put in localhost in new PDO, but still the same. Does anybody have a clue to what is wrong?

Best Regards
Mads

Comment: Did you check the port number as well as changing the host? Does your local MySql server have a username and password you need?

Comment: MySQL Workbench is not a database management system. MySQL is.

Comment: Are you sure mysql is running on your localhost?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have an easier time knowing what's not working if you echo the exception being thrown.

Your code

```
} catch (PDOException $e) {  
  $error = 'ERROR - Connection to DB failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  echo "Connection failed";
}
```

doesn't actually print the exception! Try this instead:

```
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = 'ERROR - Connection to DB failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    echo $error;
}
```

That will at least give you some helpful debugging info.

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick answer. Now i get this error with your code:

ERROR - Connection to DB failed: could not find driver

Comment: This should solve the problem:


<?php 
 
 // Establish connection to DB using PDO
 try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', '');
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
  echo "Connected!";
 } catch (PDOException $e) {  
  $error = 'ERROR - Connection to DB failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  echo $error;
  
  exit();
 }

?>

Comment: hm It dosent solve the problem anyway, so if somebody still have an idea i would love it :-)

Comment: You may need to enable this in your php.ini.
From the XAMPP control panel, click the "Config" button for the Apache Module, then click "PHP(php.ini)". Search for the line that contains something like `;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` and remove the `;`. Then save that file, and restart apache.

NOTE: I've running xampp on Windows, so obviously you won't be searching for a .dll on a mac--but look for the line related to pdo_mysql, and uncomment it.

Comment: not all people use xampp .l need to use with php.ini because l installed manually